# regularity of finite type $k$-schemes by base changing to $\bar{k}$ and an equality of dimensions of tangent spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For reference I'm trying to understand section 12.2.16 of Vakil's FOAG. Let $X$ be a finite type $k$-scheme and $p$ a closed point with residue field $k'/k$, a finite *separable* extension of degree $d$. Let $\pi: X_{\bar{k}} \to X$ be the projection morphism. It's easy to see that $k' \otimes_k \bar{k} \cong \bar{k}^d$ as rings, so the fibre over $p$ is $\pi^{-1}(p) = \sqcup_d \mathrm{Spec}(\bar{k})$. Call these $d$ pre-images $p_1, \dots, p_d$. For the sake of this question, since regularity can be checked pointwise, we may assume $X = \mathrm{Spec} A$ and $p$ corresponds to a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $A$. One can show that the fibre is the closed subscheme defined by $\mathrm{Spec}((A \otimes_k \bar{k})/(\mathfrak{m} \otimes_k \bar{k}))$. Vakil claims we have the equality
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{d} \dim_{\bar{k}}(T_{X_{\bar{k}}, p_i}) = d \cdot \dim_{k'}(T_{X, p}).
$$
I can't figure out how to prove it. Write $r := \dim_{k'}(T_{X, p})$. He suggests using the fact that $$(\mathfrak{m} \otimes_k \bar{k})/(\mathfrak{m}^2 \otimes_k \bar{k}) \cong \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2 \otimes_k \bar{k} = \bar{k}^{dr},$$ which means I only have to show that the dimension of $(\mathfrak{m} \otimes_k \bar{k})/(\mathfrak{m}^2 \otimes_k \bar{k})$ as a $\bar{k}$-module is the same as the sum of the dimensions of the tangent spaces of the preimages of $p$. Does anyone have any hints? I would like to understand intuitively why this equality of dimensions should be true. Once I figure this out, I can conclude that $X$ is regular at $p \iff X_{\bar{k}}$ is regular at $p_1, \dots, p_d$!

Comment: Hint: the tangent space at $p_i$ should be "the same" as the tangent space at $p$, except defined over a different field. For every function $f$ vanishing on $p$, $f(\pi(-))$ also vanishes on $p_i$, and to the same order.

Comment: So is what you saying that $\dim_{\bar{k}}(T_{X_{\bar{k}}, p_i}) = \dim_{k'}(T_{X, p})$? I would guess that one can show this using the Jacobian description of the Zariski cotangent space, which I've tried to do, but I'm still having some trouble.

Comment: Hi. I encountered literally the same problem in recent days :) (see linked thread). Could you post the answer when you solved it?

Comment: Also this result would imply that $X$ is regular at $p \iff X_{\bar{k}}$ is regular at some/any $p_i$. This is a stronger result that Vakil claims to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key step in proving it the way Vakil is after is understanding why $(\mathfrak{m}\otimes_{k'}\overline{k})/(\mathfrak{m}\otimes_{k'}\overline{k})^2$ decomposes as the direct sum of the tangent spaces at each of the $p_i$. First, we note the fact that the $p_i$ are exactly the preimages of $p$ (combined with the fact that $k'$ is separable) implies that $(\mathfrak{m}\otimes_{k'}\overline{k})=\mathfrak{m}_1\mathfrak{m}_2\cdots\mathfrak{m}_d$ where the ideals on the right hand side are the ideals of the points $p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_d$.

Next, since for commutative rings and comaximal ideals $I_1,\cdots,I_n$ we have $I_1I_2\cdots I_n=I_1\cap I_2\cap\cdots\cap I_n$, we may apply the Chinese remainder theorem to get that $A'/(\mathfrak{m}_1\mathfrak{m}_2\cdots\mathfrak{m}_d) \cong \prod A'/\mathfrak{m}_i$. So $$(\mathfrak{m}\otimes_{k'}\overline{k})/(\mathfrak{m}\otimes_{k'}\overline{k})^2= (\mathfrak{m}\otimes_{k'}\overline{k}) \otimes_{A'} A'/(\mathfrak{m}\otimes_{k'}\overline{k})$$ and we get that the RHS is isomorphic to $(\mathfrak{m}_1\cdots\mathfrak{m}_d)\otimes_{A'} \prod A/\mathfrak{m}_i $.

Since tensor product and product commute for finitely presented modules, it remains to see what happens to each $(\mathfrak{m}_1\cdots\mathfrak{m}_d)\otimes_{A'} A/\mathfrak{m}_i $. But this is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{m}_i/\mathfrak{m}_i^2$ via the map sending $x_1x_2\cdots x_d\mapsto x_1x_2\cdots x_d\mod \mathfrak{m}_i^2$, and since finite products agree with direct sums in module categories, we get the desired isomorphism between $(\mathfrak{m}\otimes_{k'}\overline{k})/(\mathfrak{m}\otimes_{k'}\overline{k})^2$ and $\bigoplus \mathfrak{m}_i/\mathfrak{m}_i^2$.

Comment: This certainly seems to be what he was after! Thanks for the clear explanation. The part that was confusing me was your claim that $(\mathfrak{m}\otimes_{k}\overline{k})=\mathfrak{m}_1\mathfrak{m}_2\cdots\mathfrak{m}_d$. I guess this follows from the fact that the fibre over $p$ is $\mathrm{Spec}(A'/(\mathfrak{m} \otimes_k \bar{k})) = \mathrm{Spec}(B)$ where we know $B$ is isomorphic to the product of $d$ copies of $\bar{k}$, and hence a reduced dimension 0 ring with the $\mathfrak{m}_i$'s as the minimal primes.

Comment: As you mentioned the product is the intersection, which must be 0 as the ring is reduced, which implies that the product is exactly $(\mathfrak{m}\otimes_{k}\overline{k})$ in the ring $A'$.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it was exactly what I was looking for, but I'm going to try to fix/clarify my argument below while I'm on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial answer. I would still like to understand @KReiser's comment better. Also I think it's quite clear that I'm not doing whatever Vakil was thinking of.

We can write $A = k[x_1, \dots, x_n]/(f_1, \dots, f_r)$, so $A' = \bar{k}[x_1, \dots, x_n]/(f_1, \dots, f_r)$. Let $q \in X_{\bar{k}}$ be a preimage of $p$. Suppose $p$ corresponds to a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $A$, and $q$ corresponds to a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{n}$ of $A'$. Let $$J := \left( \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i} \right)_{1 \leq i \leq n, 1 \leq j \leq r}$$ be the Jacobian matrix (on $X$) w.r.t. this presentation. The Jacobian gives a linear map $A^r \to A^n$, and its cokernel is the module of relative differentials $\Omega_{A/k}$. Then (correct me if I'm wrong) we can consider the Jacobian for $X_{\bar{k}}$, call this $J'$, by considering the same matrix, but now the elements are thought of as elements of $A'$ under the natural inclusion $A \subset A'$. Since $\bar{k}$ is algebraically closed, we get an isomorphism of the cotangent space $T_{X_{\bar{k}}, q}^\vee = \mathfrak{n}/\mathfrak{n}^2$ with the cokernel of the Jacobian $J'_p : \bar{k}^r \to \bar{k}^n$, which is also isomorphic to $\Omega_{A'/\bar{k}} \otimes_{A'} A'/\mathfrak{n}$ (by 12.2.G or 21.2.19 in Vakil). We get $J'_p$ by reducing all the elements of $J'$ modulo $\mathfrak{n}$.

It is claimed in remark 21.3.10 in Vakil that the Jacobian description of the cotangent space holds for separable closed points. For the separable closed point $p \in X$, this means $T_{X, p}^\vee = \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2 \cong \Omega_{A/k} \otimes_A k'$. The last module is the cokernel of $J_p$, obtained by reducing the elements of $J$ modulo $\mathfrak{m}$.

Suppose $A$ has dimension $d$ (so also $A'$, sorry for using $d$ again here). Let $I$ be the ideal of $A$ generated by all the $n-d$ minors of $J$ and $I'$ the ideal of $A'$ generated by all the $n-d$ minors of $J'$. Then $p$ (resp. $q$) is regular iff $J_p$ (resp. $J_q'$) has corank $d$ iff $I \nsubseteq \mathfrak{m}$ (resp. $I' \nsubseteq \mathfrak{n}$). I think $I' = I \otimes_k \bar{k}$ (probably trivially). Then if $p$ is a singular point, $I \subseteq \mathfrak{m} \implies I' \subseteq \mathfrak{m} \otimes_k \bar{k}$. But the fact that $q$ is a preimage of $p$ implies that $\mathfrak{m} \otimes_k \bar{k} \subseteq \mathfrak{n}$, and hence $q$ is singular as well. In other words, we've proven that if $X_{\bar{k}}$ is regular at some/any $p_i$, then $X$ is regular at $p$. I'm not sure how to prove the opposite implication yet.

If $X_{\bar{k}}$ is singular at each $p_i$, then $I' \subseteq \mathfrak{n}_{i}$ for each $i$. Working in the quotient ring $B=A'/(\mathfrak{m} \otimes_k \bar{k}) = k' \otimes_k \bar{k}$, we know $B$ is reduced of dimension $0$ with finitely many minimal prime ideals $\mathfrak{n}_1, \dots, \mathfrak{n}_d$. The reduction of $I'$ in $B$ is thus contained in the nilradical, which is the zero ideal by reducedness. This in turn implies that $I' \subseteq \mathfrak{m} \otimes_k \bar{k}$. From here maybe we can use faithful flatness or something to conclude $I \subseteq \mathfrak{m}$.

EDIT: In response to KReiser's comment below, we prove that if $f \in k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is a polynomial then $f$ vanishes at $p$ iff $f$ vanishes at each $p_i$. We know that vanishing at $p$ is the same as being contained in the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $A$ and vanishing at each $p_i$ is the same as being contained in $\mathfrak{m}_i$ for each $i = 1, \dots, d$, where the $\mathfrak{m}_i$ are the maximal ideals of $A'$ corresponding to the points $p_i$ as in the answer above. We use the fact that $(\mathfrak{m}\otimes_{k'}\overline{k})=\mathfrak{m}_1\mathfrak{m}_2\cdots\mathfrak{m}_d = \mathfrak{m}_1 \cap \cdots \cap \mathfrak{m}_d$. It's easy to see that if $f \in \mathfrak{m}$, then $f \in \mathfrak{m}_i$ for all $i$. Conversely, if $f \in \mathfrak{m}_i$ for all $i$, then $f \in (\mathfrak{m} \otimes_k \bar{k})$, but since $f$ has $k$-coefficients we can conclude $f \in \mathfrak{m}$. From this, the above argument makes sense as the entries of $J'$ are polynomials with coefficients in $k$ so we don't need faithful flatness or whatever I was thinking.

Comment: If you're looking to make this approach work, you should prove the following: for a polynomial with coefficients in $k$, vanishing on $p$ is equivalent to vanishing on $p_i$ for each $p_i$. Then you may conclude that the appropriate minors of the Jacobian have nonvanishing determinant at each point. The observation that the Jacobian matrix is the same is what my hint was getting at: the tangent spaces are the same, just defined over different fields.

Comment: @KReiser: But then the conclusion from your hint would be $\dim_{\bar{k}}(T_{X_{\bar{k}}, p_i}) = \dim_{k'}(T_{X, p})$? Was just a bit irritated since this is much stronger then $\sum_{i=1}^{d} \dim_{\bar{k}}(T_{X_{\bar{k}}, p_i}) = d \cdot \dim_{k'}(T_{X, p})$ und futhermore in this case why we need to consider this sum? Indeed, $\dim_{\bar{k}}(T_{X_{\bar{k}}, p_i}) = \dim_{k'}(T_{X, p})$ would provide $\dim_{\bar{k}}(T_{X_{\bar{k}}, p_i}) = \dim X_{\bar{k}} \Leftrightarrow \dim_{k'}(T_{X, p})= X$ since (pure) dimensions of $X$ and $X_{\bar{k}}$ coinside. Or did I misunderstood your hint?

Comment: This is not stronger! Part (d) of the given exercise makes it a trivial conclusion from the equality.

Comment: @KReiser: Yes, of course, you are right. My point was that if we from $(\mathfrak{m} \otimes_k \bar{k})/(\mathfrak{m}^2 \otimes_k \bar{k}) \cong \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2 \otimes_k \bar{k}$ and the sequence in (b) can instantly deduce the statement $\dim_{\bar{k}}(T_{X_{\bar{k}}, p_i}) = \dim_{k'}(T_{X, p})$ , why then we need this detour over the sum identity above? That confused me.