# $(\mathfrak{m}\otimes_{k'}\overline{k})=\mathfrak{m}_1\mathfrak{m}_2\cdots\mathfrak{m}_d$ for Separated Field $k'$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My question refers to a step in @KReiser's answer in following thread: [regularity of finite type $k$-schemes by base changing to $\bar{k}$ and an equality of dimensions of tangent spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2926021/regularity-of-finite-type-k-schemes-by-base-changing-to-bark-and-an-equal)

Here the complete answer:

[image]

Here we consider the preimage $\{p_1,  ..., p_d\}= \pi^{-1}(p)$ of a closed point $p \in X$ (so it corresponds to a maximal ideal $m$) under the morphism $\pi: X \otimes {\bar{k}} =X_{\bar{k}} \to X$.We know that it has the shape $\pi^{-1}(p) = \sqcup_d \mathrm{Spec}(\bar{k})$.

Let the residual field $k' := Frac(\mathcal{O}_{X,p})$ at $p$ be a separable (!) extension of degree $d$ of $k$. Denote futhermore by $m_i$ the maximal ideals corresponding to preimages $p_i$ of $p$.

My question is how to see that $$(\mathfrak{m}\otimes_{k'}\overline{k})=\mathfrak{m}_1\mathfrak{m}_2\cdots\mathfrak{m}_d$$ holds?

The cruical point was according to @KReiser's explanation that $k'$ is separable but here I don't see how to use it.

Attempts: I know that one can characterize separableness $k'$ by criterion $rad(k' \otimes _k \overline{k}) =0$. Can I somehow make usage of this fact?

Comment: Did you read the comments under that answer? The OP of that question outlined a proof.

Comment: @KReiser: ggg argued in one of his comments below that (obviously)$A'/(\mathfrak{m} \otimes_{k'} \bar{k}) = \oplus_d \bar{k}$ holds. I don't see how is explicitely used this and the fact that $k'$ is separable to get the desired equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathfrak{m}\otimes_k\overline{k}$ is the ideal of the fiber over $p$. The fiber is Spec of $A'/(\mathfrak{m}\otimes\overline{k})$, and this ring is isomorphic to $(A/\mathfrak{m})\otimes_{k} \overline{k}$, which is further isomorphic to $k'\otimes_k \overline{k}$, so this ring is isomorphic to $\overline{k}^d$ (this last isomorphism is where we used separability). From here, we know that $\mathfrak{m}\otimes_k\overline{k}$ factors as a product of maximal ideals by considering it's primary decomposition (every primary ideal in the decomposition must be a power of a maximal ideal, but since the quotient is reduced, all of these powers must be 1, and since they're all comaximal, the intersection is exactly the product).

Comment: Why do we need for the isomorphism $k'\otimes_k \overline{k} \cong \overline{k}^d$ separability of $k'$? I guess this follows just from the fact that $k' \cong k^d $ since $[k':k]=d$ and the fact that tensoring respects products. Do I overlook something?

Comment: ah yes, I guess I see it. You mean it as a ***ring isomorphism*** not module isomorphism? :)

Comment: The reason we need separability is that the given ring isomorphism is not true without it. Let $k=\Bbb F_2(t)$ with $k'=k(\sqrt{t})$, a degree-2 extension of $k$. Then $k'\otimes_k\overline{k}\cong k[X]/(X^2-t)\otimes_k\overline{k} \cong \overline{k}[X]/(X^2-t)\cong \overline{k}[X]/((X-\sqrt{t})^2)$ which is not reduced, so it cannot be a product of fields.